# create an xml file using a shell script

Tags: sql, unix, shell, sed, awk

I have a table with two columns

```
column_1 column_1
12345     12345
73255     73255
71377     71377
```

Now i want to create an xml like

```
<header>
<value>12345</value>
<value>73255</value>
<value>71377</value>
<footer>
```

basically i need to use a select query and put any one of the fields into the values of xml.

could you please suggest how could this be done in an easiest way?
much appreciate your help.

Comment: That depends on what kind of database you have and what command-line DB client you have available.

Comment: i am connecting to data base using sqlplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagine you have selected from the database and stored those columns in a file called "file"

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{ print "<header>"}
NR>1{  print "<value>"$1"</value>" }
END{ print "<footer>"}' file
```

on the command line

```
# ./shell.sh
<header>
<value>12345</value>
<value>73255</value>
<value>71377</value>
<footer>
```