# How to fill an XML file with random data?

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, shell

I have an auto-generated XML file which I have to fill with values from an oracle database or with a randomly-generated sequence.

For example:

```
<ns1:message>
        <ns1:messageId>        </ns1:messageId>
        <ns1:languageCode>  </ns1:languageCode>
</ns1:message>
```

`<messageId>` should be filled a randomly **sequence**.

`<ns1:languageCode>` should be filled with a **value from the database.**

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried the solution from this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606328/create-an-xml-file-using-a-shell-script but I wonder if it is possible to do it without exporting the values first in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 tasks here actually.

- Producing XML with .NET.

The best way I see so far is using [LinqToXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). You can read here, hot to [create XML trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387068).

```
var xmlTree = new XElement("message", 
         new XElement("messageId", GetRandomMessageId()), 
         new XElement("languageCode", GetRandomLanguageCode()));
```

- Implementing the methods to generate random data
  `GetRandomMessageId`(), `GetRandomLanguageCode`().

Use .NET [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) to make this happen.

Just as an example:

```
public string GetRandomMessageId()
{
  return "messageId_" + new Random(100);
}
```

You can customize what ever you like.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander                                                   As I'm not very far with .Net could you post an example for the situation where I should have value from the database?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean?

Comment: In tag '<ns1:languageCode>  </ns1:languageCode>' I need to have the following value: select value from v_domaine;

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate some kind of random data you should maybe take a look into [AutoPoco](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the sequence using a **cryptographically-secure** random number generator **do not use** the `System.Random` class.  Instead use a

`System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`

such as

`System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

If it does not matter that the numbers are cryptographically random, then you can use the `System.Random` class.

An example on the Microsoft Developer Network As well as the documentation for the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` can be found at [MSDN: RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).